# Alternative to Nested For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have two data sets:
competitor_data - contains competitors for a given product as well as the price and date when the competitor prices were collected.

product_price - the date of each price change.

```
competitor_data <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                            crawl_date=c("2014-04-05", "2014-04-22", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-22","2014-06-05", "2014-06-22",
                                   "2014-05-08", "2014-06-17", "2014-06-09", "2014-06-14","2014-07-01", "2014-08-04"),
                            competitor =c("amazon","apple","google","facebook","alibaba","tencent","ebay","bestbuy","gamespot","louis vuitton","gucci","tesla"),
                            competitor_price =c(2.5,2.35,1.99,2.01,2.22,2.52,5.32,5.56,5.01,6.01,5.86,5.96), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

competitor_data$crawl_date = as.Date(competitor_data$crawl_date)
```

#

```
product_price <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                                      date=c("2014-05-05", "2014-06-22", "2014-07-05", "2014-08-31","2014-05-03", "2014-02-22",
                                                  "2014-05-21", "2014-06-19", "2014-03-09", "2014-06-22","2014-07-03", "2014-09-08"),
                                    price =c(2.12,2.31,2.29,2.01,2.04,2.09,5.22,5.36,5.21,5.91,5.36,5.56), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

product_price$date = as.Date(product_price$date)
```

Objective

- For a given product in product_price, for each record (date), find
  the relevant crawl_date price from competitor_data.
- Compare product_price$price to lowest competitor_data$competitor_price.
- If product_price$price <= competitor_data$competitor_price, then create a new column to flag 1 (price_leader) else flag 0 (price_leader)

My script below using nested for loops but it takes over 24 hours to process 5000 unique product_id:

```
unique_skus <- unique(product_price$productId)
all_competitive_data <- data.frame()
mid_step_data <- data.frame()

start_time <-Sys.time()
for (i in 1:length(unique_skus)){
  step1 <- subset(product_price, productId == unique_skus[i])
  transact_dates = unique(step1$date)
  for (a in 1:length(transact_dates)){
    step2 <- subset(step1, date ==transact_dates[a])
    step3 <- inner_join(step2,competitor_data, by='productId')
    if (nrow(subset(step3, date > crawl_date)) == 0){
      step3 <- step3[ order(step3$crawl_date , decreasing = FALSE ),]
      competitor_price <- head(step3,1)$competitor_price
      step2$competitor_price = competitor_price
    }
    else {
      step4 <- subset(step3, date > crawl_date)
      step4 <- step4[ order(step4$crawl_date , decreasing = TRUE ),]
      competitor_price <- head(step4,1)$competitor_price
      step2$competitor_price = competitor_price
    }
    step2$price_leader <- ifelse(step2$price <= step2$competitor_price, 1, 0)
    mid_step_data = rbind(mid_step_data,step2)
  }
  all_competitive_data <- rbind(all_competitive_data,mid_step_data)
}
Sys.time()-start_time
all_competitive_data = unique(all_competitive_data)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this quickly perhaps using dplyr?

Comment: why not merge the two data sets by product id and date, then compare the two price columns

Comment: Because crawl_date does not necessarily map to date. Please see if statement in my code.

Comment: so youre picking the price on the next closest date, so after the merge use a last observation carried forward function to fill in the NAs

Comment: This is still using a for loop right? Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
competitor_data <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                              crawl_date=c("2014-04-05", "2014-04-22", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-22","2014-06-05", "2014-06-22",
                                           "2014-05-08", "2014-06-17", "2014-06-09", "2014-06-14","2014-07-01", "2014-08-04"),
                              competitor =c("amazon","apple","google","facebook","alibaba","tencent","ebay","bestbuy","gamespot","louis vuitton","gucci","tesla"),
                              competitor_price =c(2.5,2.35,1.99,2.01,2.22,2.52,5.32,5.56,5.01,6.01,5.86,5.96), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

competitor_data$crawl_date = as.Date(competitor_data$crawl_date)
#
product_price <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                            date=c("2014-05-05", "2014-06-22", "2014-07-05", "2014-08-31","2014-05-03", "2014-02-22",
                                   "2014-05-21", "2014-06-19", "2014-03-09", "2014-06-22","2014-07-03", "2014-09-08"),
                            price =c(2.12,2.31,2.29,2.01,2.04,2.09,5.22,5.36,5.21,5.91,5.36,5.56), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

product_price$date = as.Date(product_price$date)
```

Use this function to fill a vector with NAs forward then backward

```
## fill in NAs
f <- function(..., lead = NA) {
  # f(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, lead = NULL)
  x <- c(lead, c(...))
  head(zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE),
       if (is.null(lead)) length(x) else -length(lead))
}
```

Merge the two by product and date. We pad the first price by product with an extra NA so this will effectively use the previous price when we fill in the NAs

Then do the comparison of price and competitor price. The last step is just some cleaning up to prove it is the same result

```
dd <- merge(product_price, competitor_data,
            by.y = c('productId', 'crawl_date'),
            by.x = c('productId', 'date'), all = TRUE)
dd$competitor_price <-
  unlist(sapply(split(dd$competitor_price, dd$productId), f))
dd$price_leader <- +(dd$price <= dd$competitor_price)
(res1 <- `rownames<-`(dd[!is.na(dd$price_leader), -4], NULL))

#    productId       date price competitor_price price_leader
# 1     banana 2014-02-22  2.09             2.50            1
# 2     banana 2014-05-03  2.04             2.35            1
# 3     banana 2014-05-05  2.12             2.35            1
# 4     banana 2014-06-22  2.31             2.22            0
# 5     banana 2014-07-05  2.29             2.52            1
# 6     banana 2014-08-31  2.01             2.52            1
# 7        fig 2014-03-09  5.21             5.32            1
# 8        fig 2014-05-21  5.22             5.32            1
# 9        fig 2014-06-19  5.36             5.56            1
# 10       fig 2014-06-22  5.91             5.56            0
# 11       fig 2014-07-03  5.36             5.86            1
# 12       fig 2014-09-08  5.56             5.96            1

res0 <- `rownames<-`(all_competitive_data[
  order(all_competitive_data$productId, all_competitive_data$date), ], NULL)

all.equal(res0, res1)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

You can change any of these steps to dplyr or data.table syntax; I don't use either one, but it should be straight-forward:

```
library('dplyr')
dd <- full_join(product_price, competitor_data,
                by = c(
                  'productId' = 'productId',
                  'date' = 'crawl_date'
                )
) %>% arrange(productId, date)

dd %>% group_by(productId) %>%
  mutate(
    competitor_price = f(competitor_price),
    price_leader = as.integer(price <= competitor_price)
) %>% filter(!is.na(price_leader)) %>% select(-competitor)

# Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
# Groups: productId [2]
# 
#      productId       date price competitor_price price_leader
#          <chr>     <date> <dbl>            <dbl>        <int>
#   1     banana 2014-02-22  2.09             2.50            1
#   2     banana 2014-05-03  2.04             2.35            1
#   3     banana 2014-05-05  2.12             2.35            1
#   4     banana 2014-06-22  2.31             2.22            0
#   5     banana 2014-07-05  2.29             2.52            1
#   6     banana 2014-08-31  2.01             2.52            1
#   7        fig 2014-03-09  5.21             5.32            1
#   8        fig 2014-05-21  5.22             5.32            1
#   9        fig 2014-06-19  5.36             5.56            1
#   10       fig 2014-06-22  5.91             5.56            0
#   11       fig 2014-07-03  5.36             5.86            1
#   12       fig 2014-09-08  5.56             5.96            1
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution uses dplyr join to match. (NOTE:I changed "crawl_date" to "date" so that dplyr join would select the matching columns automatically. It can be  matched explicitly by using something like

```
by=c('productId'='productId', date'='crawl_date')
```

as a parameter to join.

```
competitor_data <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                              date=c("2014-04-05", "2014-04-22", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-22","2014-06-05", "2014-06-22",
                                           "2014-05-08", "2014-06-17", "2014-06-09", "2014-06-14","2014-07-01", "2014-08-04"),
                              competitor =c("amazon","apple","google","facebook","alibaba","tencent","ebay","bestbuy","ga**strong text**mespot","louis vuitton","gucci","tesla"),
                              competitor_price =c(2.5,2.35,1.99,2.01,2.22,2.52,5.32,5.56,5.01,6.01,5.86,5.96), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

competitor_data$date = as.Date(competitor_data$date)

product_price <- data.frame(productId=c('banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','banana', 'banana','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig','fig', 'fig'),
                            date=c("2014-05-05", "2014-06-22", "2014-07-05", "2014-08-31","2014-05-03", "2014-02-22",
                                   "2014-05-21", "2014-06-19", "2014-03-09", "2014-06-22","2014-07-03", "2014-09-08"),
                            price =c(2.12,2.31,2.29,2.01,2.04,2.09,5.22,5.36,5.21,5.91,5.36,5.56), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

product_price$date = as.Date(product_price$date)

require(dplyr)
joined <- product_price %>% left_join(competitor_data)
joined$leader <- as.integer(joined$price <= joined$competitor_price)

joined
```

The resulting data frame is

```
   productId       date price competitor competitor_price leader
1     banana 2014-05-05  2.12     google             1.99      0
2     banana 2014-06-22  2.31    tencent             2.52      1
3     banana 2014-07-05  2.29       <NA>               NA     NA
4     banana 2014-08-31  2.01       <NA>               NA     NA
5     banana 2014-05-03  2.04       <NA>               NA     NA
6     banana 2014-02-22  2.09       <NA>               NA     NA
7        fig 2014-05-21  5.22       <NA>               NA     NA
8        fig 2014-06-19  5.36       <NA>               NA     NA
9        fig 2014-03-09  5.21       <NA>               NA     NA
10       fig 2014-06-22  5.91       <NA>               NA     NA
11       fig 2014-07-03  5.36       <NA>               NA     NA
12       fig 2014-09-08  5.56       <NA>               NA     NA
>
```

Comment: What this is missing is my if statement. date and crawl_date are not necessarily the same. For a given date, we take the the closest crawl_date (a crawl_date before date). Please see my if statements. I put the logic in.